# dispatchTouchEvent forced normal view click listener not to work

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a QR code Scanner, where i need to zoom scanner.

I have some buttons on scanner.The problem is after adding dispatchTouchevent,
clicklistener to buttons stopped working.

if i remove dipatchTouchEvent, click actions works fine but the Scanner zooming does not work. So dipatchTouchEvent i must add.

I need both  button  onclicklisener and dipatchTouchEvent. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you returning true or false? Are you calling super.dispatchTouchEvent? Please post your code.

Comment: this is my code    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        boolean b = scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

        boolean c = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

        return b || c || super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

Comment: after adding this, clicklistner is not working  LinlayoutMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                ChatListFragment chatListFragment = new ChatListFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_content,chatListFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be returning `super.dispatchTouchEvent` like this, otherwise on the touch down the `gestureDetector` will consume event, with no possibilty of a following click event.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: But instead of returning super.onTouchEvent (e) we need to return super.dispatchTouchEvent(e) only then it works.    Thanks